# How to loop through array of arrays in reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs

How can i loop through array of arrays in react. Currently when i try to loop through the array, I get the following error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

This is how the data structure looks like

[image]

Here is what i have implemented so far

```
                {what_you_will_learn.map(item => (
                  <Grid
                    item
                    lg={6}
                    md={6}
                    key={item}
                    className="what-you-get__item what-you-get__item--columns"
                  >
                    <span className="udi udi-check what-you-get__icon">
                      <i className="fa fa-check" style="font-size:24px"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span className="what-you-get__text">{item[0]}</span>
                  </Grid>
                ))}
```

Comment: you're doing it correctly, problem is, error you're getting could be from the initial state value

Comment: How is `what_you_will_learn` instantiated ?

Comment: you should check that `what_you_will_learn` exists. `what_you_will_learn && what_you_will_learn.length>0?what_you_will_learn.map....?null`

Comment: Just check this condition `{what_you_will_learn && what_you_will_learn.length && what_you_will_learn.map(...)`

Comment: logging `what_you_will_learn` returns an array of arrays.

Comment: if what_will_you_learn is in state, check if it is available before map like other people suggested but you need to extract the variable first in render method, or you can do `this.state.map()`

Comment: @Sameer `what_you_will_learn` is not in state, its an attribute of an object that i access directly from the store and pass as a prop.

Comment: pass as a prop to what? a component? if yes, then it will be accessed as `props.what_you_will_learn`, if component is functional or stateless. If component is statefull then `this.props.what_you_will_learn`